# How to add a newline to a variable?

Tags: variables, autohotkey

I'm trying to append a trailing newline to a variable like:

```
data := "text"
Clipboard := data "\n"
```

But that leads to a data with literal \n. All other tries without quotation marks leads to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a backslash `\` AHK uses a backtick `` ` ``.
So you'd do a line feed character with `` `n ``, or a carriage return with `` `r ``, or a horizontal tab with `` `t ``, and so on.

```
data := "text"
Clipboard := data "`n"
```